# CQ5/AEM Dispatcher not retaining charset information

Tags: character-encoding, aem, dispatcher

When we pull content from our publish instances, we get a content type header that states that the content is "charset=utf-8". When this files is served from the dispatcher that charset information is missing. This isn't a problem for web pages which look at the encoding declared in the html, however there are a number of third party libraries, including one from Adobe, that processes this as iso-8859-1 if that content type declaration isn't there.

I'm attempting to determine if it's possible for the dispatcher to be configured to add this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the dispatcher caches only the content, with no headers. If the page is loaded from the cache, it'll behave pretty much like any other static file served by the Apache. The dispatcher itself doesn't have any charset configuration, but I think that adding

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

to the Apache configuration should fix the issue. More info can be found in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset).

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone but if you've created from a Java servlet, make sure that you set up headers first. In author/publish, it seems able to handle if these aren't set up because of the other configuration and how the pages are accessed.

So the following (where you have your DOGET method), you need to specify your headers as the very first thing as otherwise the encoding won't be set correctly.

```
protected void doGet(@Nonnull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException { 
      response.setContentType(com.adobe.granite.rest.Constants.CT_JSON); 
      response.setCharacterEncoding(com.adobe.granite.rest.Constants.DEFAULT_CHARSET); 
....
}
```

In my instance, AEM and web server had the correct info but the issue was that the setting of encoding and content type happened later on when it should be defined immediately.